# Efficiently delete nested records using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to delete a large set of nested records from SQLAlchemy.  To do so, I need to query the data and then use the session to delete it.  My problem is that I'm running out of memory on the query.

Specifically, I have classes `CA`, `CB`, `CC`, and `CD`.  `CA` uses `name` as the primary key and `CB` has an autoincrement `CBId` column as its primary key.  An instance of `CA` contains about 1000 instances of `CB` which, in turn contains 1000 instances of `CC` and about eight million instances of `CD`.

What I want to emit to the database is, essentially:

```
 DELETE FROM CCTable WHERE CBId IN (SELECT CBId FROM CBTable WHERE Name = ?)
 DELETE FROM CDTable WHERE CBId IN (SELECT CBId FROM CBTable WHERE Name = ?)
 DELETE FROM CBTable WHERE Name = ?
 DELETE FROM CATable WHERE Name = ?
```

What I'm currently trying is:

```
    data = self._context.query(CA) \
            .filter_by(name = name_to_delete) \
            .options(
                joinedload('CB').options(joinedload('CC'), joinedload('CD')) 
            ).first() 
    if data:
        context.delete(data)
        self._context.commit()
```

This fails, not unexpectedly, with OUT OF MEMORY.

How can I accomplish my goal in SQLAlchemy?

Comment: Is using `DELETE CASCADE` o the database directly not an option?

Comment: @van On data load  I could use ON DELETE CASCADE in the sqlite database, but I find the SQLAlchemy documentation on configuring this setup unclear.

Comment: Well, if you configure `ON DELETE CASCADE`, you do not have to worry about removing the orphaned children when you delete a row from `CATable` at all as the database will take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

*The `ON DELETE CASCADE` option mentioned in the comments could be a solution on the database level.*

Otherwise, your query basically loads the whole network of the objects starting from `CA` into memory, which is the most likely cause of your issue. Furthermore, even if it was not, by doing `context.delete(data)` you are only deleting the instance of `CA` as `data` will be a `CA` instance, and unless your relationships define correctly [`cascade`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/cascades.html#unitofwork-cascades), the related rows will not be deleted in the database.

And if you have configured those properly, the issue of a need to load everything into memory in order to delete it completely is not the approach one should take.

**Solution: delete directly on the database (without data load)**

With the example model defined below:

```
class CA(Base):
    __tablename__ = "ca_table"
    name = Column(String, primary_key=True)

    cbs = relationship("CB", back_populates="ca")


class CB(Base):
    __tablename__ = "cb_table"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, index=True)
    name = Column(ForeignKey(CA.name))

    ca = relationship(CA, back_populates="cbs")
    ccs = relationship("CC", back_populates="cb")
    cds = relationship("CD", back_populates="cb")


class CC(Base):
    __tablename__ = "cc_table"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, index=True)
    cb_id = Column(ForeignKey(CB.id))

    cb = relationship(CB, back_populates="ccs")


class CD(Base):
    __tablename__ = "cd_table"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, index=True)
    cb_id = Column(ForeignKey(CB.id))

    cb = relationship(CB, back_populates="cds")
```

I would implement the deletion as per below:

```
def delete_a(session, name_to_delete):
    q = session.query(CD).filter(CD.cb.has(CB.name == name_to_delete))
    q.delete(synchronize_session=False)

    q = session.query(CC).filter(CC.cb.has(CB.name == name_to_delete))
    q.delete(synchronize_session=False)

    q = session.query(CB).filter(CB.name == name_to_delete)
    q.delete(synchronize_session=False)

    q = session.query(CA).filter(CA.name == name_to_delete)
    q.delete(synchronize_session=False)

    session.commit()


delete_a(session, "some_a_name")
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed and helpful example.  My concern here is that I require  cyclical relationships (CB ->CC -CB and CB->CD->CB) to make it work.  I think the ON DELETE CASCADE at the database level is my solution, but I'm using SQLite and it's difficult to modify the database after the fact to support the CASCADEs and not entirely clear to me how to establish them through a Base descendant class in the first place.